Why are bottom plates and studs sometimes green near the base? Does this matter when remodeling?
While remodeling the kitchen of a recently acquired standalone single-family residence, I discovered a green coating or treatment had been applied to the base of the studs, the bottom plates, and the inner side of the exterior sheathing, presumably by the builder (2005).
Does anyone know what chemical or substance was used on these wall panels and if I need to apply/reapply it to any (untreated) boards added during the remodeling process?


The green is a dye put in a Borate used to treat the wood.
It's to prevent termites and other insects as well as mold from attacking the wood.
Do you need to treat any new wood you will use?  Depends on if the local codes make it necessary.
